# How to patch the localPost except for summary using GMB API?

Tags: google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I would like to know how we can edit localPost except for summary.

I created the request like following.

URL: https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/23432/locations/23423/localPosts/23432?updateMask=summary&updateMask=title

Request body

```
{
  "summary": "AAAA",
  "event": {
    "title": "TEST TITLE"
  }
}
```

However, I can only edit summary, not the other field.

I tried following requet URLs as well.

https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/23432/locations/23423/localPosts/23432?updateMask=summary,title
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/23432/locations/23423/localPosts/23432?updateMask=title

But, GMB API response dose not give me any error.
So, it looks like fine.

Do have you have any idea for this?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should chain your parameters:

?updateMask=summary,event.title